# Move files to Sub-Directories via list.txt

Tags: scripts, directory, batch

I have this Batch file that works quite well, however, I went back to Ubuntu and need to convert these .bat into .sh files.

This is the code I have on Windows and it works well.

```
@echo off /u

cd /d "C:\Users\rivers\Desktop\data\sprite" 2>nul || exit /b 
           
for /f ^usebackq^tokens^=*^delims^= %%i in =;(` 
     type .\"ListedFiles.txt" ^| findstr . `);= do 2>nul =;( 
         robocopy .\. "%%~dpi\." "%%~nxi" /mov /njh | find "100%"
        );= || echo; Check Your Folder\File path: "%%~dpi" "%%~nxi"
```

This moves files to their folders using this code snippet. It loops through all the files and sends them to their destined folder that is in the ListedFiles.txt.
I need to replicate this and get it working on Linux. What I tried already doesn't seem to do the job.

`while IFS= read -r file; do cp --parents -f -r "$file" ~/Desktop/Folder/; done < ~/Desktop/ListedFiles.txt`

EDIT: TheStructure of ListedFiles.txt is as follows:
`/home/user/Documents/atgrf/guild_r.bmp`
Most directories have between 1 and 3 sub-directories.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my answer this morning using `rsync` and `--files-from`.

`rsync -a /home/user/Desktop/data/ --files-from=/home/user/Desktop/ListedFiles.txt /home/user/Desktop/Folder/`